Error de compilación
tengo un pequeñito problema y es que he realizado un código el cual debe de imprimir un rombo pasándole un lado dónde debe de estar en rango 1 a 20   y siguiendo un patron, estoy aprendiendo es un ejercicio que me han asignado y lo he intentaod resolver pero sigo sin poder buscar alguna solución alternativa, debe de ser, el problema es que cuando lo ejecuto me funciona, pero tengo que pasarlo por un compilador y me salta un error de ÿ, me gustaría resolver el problema.
#include <stdio.h>

int distancia = 0;
int contador = 0;
int posinicial = 0;
int posfinal = 0;
int posinicialabajo = 0;
int posfinalabajo = 0;

void simbolo( int posicion ){
  const char caracteres [4] = {'@','.','o','.'};
  if( posicion >= 0 && posicion <= 3 ){
    printf( "%c", caracteres[posicion] );
  }
  else{
    printf( "%c", caracteres[posicion % 4] );
  }
}
void simbololinea(int lados, int columna, int posinicial, int posfinal){
  if( (columna >= posinicial && columna <= posfinal) ){
    simbolo(contador);
    if (columna < lados - 1){
      contador++;
    }
    else  {
      contador--;
    }
  }else{
    printf(" ");
  }
}
void rombo( int lados ){
  distancia = lados  * 2;
  posinicialabajo = 1;
  posfinalabajo = (lados-1) * 2;
  for( int fila = 0 ; fila < distancia - 1 ; fila++ ){
    if(fila <= lados){
      contador = 0;
      posinicial = lados - fila - 1;
      posfinal = lados + fila - 1;
    }
    else if (fila > lados) {
      contador = 0;
      posinicialabajo++;
      posfinalabajo--;
    }
    for(int columna = 0; columna < distancia - 1; columna++){
      if(fila < lados){
        if(columna == posfinal){
          simbololinea(lados, columna, posinicial, posfinal);
          continue;
        }
        simbololinea(lados, columna, posinicial, posfinal);
      }else{
        if(columna == posfinalabajo){
          simbololinea(lados, columna, posinicial, posfinal);
          continue;
        }
        simbololinea(lados, columna, posinicialabajo, posfinalabajo);
      }
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

}
int main(){
  int lados = 0;
  printf("¿Lado rombo?:");
  scanf("%d", &lados);
  printf("\n");
  if(lados > 0 && lados <= 20){
    rombo(lados);

    return 0;
  }

}



c != c++.. son dos lenguajes que si bien tienen similitudes, son distintos... en fin... Esto es c, no c++.. y otra cosa.. si tu codigo no da error, que podriamos corregir nosotros?

como puedes ver en la imagen tengo un fallo, he hecho una pregunta, soy novato.

No es un error de compilación, es un error de ejecución. Con un error de compilación te quedas sin nada "ejecutable".

Puedes considerar a C++ como una extensión de C. Agrega clases, referencias, conceptos, plantillas, tiene su propia librería estándar, etc.

El problema es que a veces la variable contador se usa cuando es negativa.
El problema se puede solucionar de este modo (aunque no es la mejor solución probablemente)
void simbololinea(int lados, int columna, int posinicial, int posfinal){
  if( (columna >= posinicial && columna <= posfinal) ){
    if (contador >= 0)
      simbolo(contador);
    if (columna < lados - 1){
      contador++;
    }
    else  {
      contador--;
    }
  }else{
    printf(" ");
  }
}

De este modo, simbolo(contador) sólo se evalúa cuando la variable es mayor o igual a cero.

Solucionado, muchas gracias por su explicación!!!!!!
